# How import Special Characters from Excel to SQLIte

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I try to import an Excel table with German special characters (ä, ö, ü, ß, Ä, Ö, Ü). These don't import properly into the SQLite database (using the firefox SQLite Manager).

Any clues how to properly import the CSV file?

Comment: Hi i want to send that kinda data to server and save in mysql table how can be its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best option I found was to save as CSV in Excel and use Windows Notepad to convert it from ANSI to UTF-8, this way I got it imported properly.

Comment: Hi i want to send that kinda data to server and save in mysql table how can be its possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly formatting your strings as UTF8?

Comment: I tried saving as UTF-8 in Excel for the CSV-data file, but the special characters did not come through in the SQLite DB